# C# Namespace, Folders, Compiler Error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, namespaces

I'm using VS 2017 v15.5.0.

I have a minimal Console project named, `Con_02`. The namespace for the main class in this project is simply `Con_02` (the class is shown below).

Within this project I add a new folder named, `Business`. Within the `Business` folder I create a class named, `Employee`. The default namespace generated by VS for the `Employee` class is `Con_02.Business`. I simplify this namespace to `Business`.

Back in my main class I instantiate `Employee`. Here is my full main class:

```
namespace Con_02 {
    class Program {
        Business.Employee e1 = new Business.Employee();

        private static void Main() { }
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Everything compiles.

Now, I create another class, `Company`, in the `Business` folder. VS generates a namespace, `Con_02.Business`.

Now, the main `Con_02.Program` class no longer compiles. Specifically, the creation of the `Business.Employee` object which had previously compiled just fine, gives me a compiler error:

> The type or namespace name 'Employee' does not exist in the namespace 'Con_02.Business' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**I'm not asking how to fix the problem so much as I'm trying to understand why compiler seems to assume a namespace relative to `Con_02`.**

Comment: And that's why you don't want duplicate namespace names.  Try `global::Business.Employee`

Comment: Either add `using Business` or `global::` as suggested above. But better just  don't use such namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a new namespace called Con_02.Business which contains Company class the Business.Employee is considered to be under Con_02.Business namespace but Con_02.Business contains nothing but Company class.

[image]

Better to change

```
namespace Con_02.Business
{
    class Company
    {
    }
}
```

to

```
namespace Business
{
    class Company
    {
    }
}
```

or just use `Employee e1 = new Employee();`

Remember namespace is only about grouping the classes.

Comment: Yea, I know what's happening and how to "fix" it but it seems odd that the compiler assumes Employee must be in the same namespace as Company. I don't like it.

Comment: So just use Employee e1 = new Employee(); then

Answer (score 0):

Add

`using Business;`

at the top of you `Program` class.

and remove The Business-part from your Employee instantiation.

OR. Use the same namespace for all you classes.